# Asara B'Teveis on a Friday

Tags: fast-days, shabbat, halacha

This year Asara B'Teveis came out on a Friday. Suppose you would Daven Mincha before Plag and Kaballas Shabbos right after Plag and come home when it is still light outside, would you be allowed to break the fast before Tzais?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to depend on who you hold by.
Shulhan Arukh O"H 249:4
אם קבל עליו להתענות בע"ש, (יט) צריך להתענות עד צאת הכוכבים, * (כ) <ב> אם לא שפירש בשעת קבלת התענית עד שישלים הצבור תפלתן. הגה: * (כא) <ג> וי"א דלא ישלים, אלא מיד ח שיוצאים מבית הכנסת, יאכל (טור ומרדכי ס"פ בכל מערבין בשם הר"מ והגהות מיימוני פ' א' מהלכות תענית). לכן (כב) בתענית יחיד לא ישלים, וטוב לפרש כן בשעת קבלת התענית; ובתענית צבור ישלים, והכי נהוג (מהרי"ל). ואם הוא [ח] תענית חלום, צריך להתענות (כג) עד צאת הכוכבים.

Mishna Berura there
(כא) וי"א דלא וכו' - האי י"א ס"ל [כד] דבין בתענית יחיד ובין בת"צ כגון עשרה בטבת שחל בע"ש לא יתענה רק עד שיצא מבהכ"נ דאז כבר קבלו שבת בתפלה שמתפללים [כה] מפלג המנחה ואילך [הוא מי"א שעות חסר רביע ואילך והשעות הן זמניות ועיין לקמן סימן רס"א] ומקרי עי"ז השלמת התענית מה שמתענה עד אחר קבלת שבת וה"ה בעיו"ט עד אחר קבלת יו"ט [ובחול גם לי"א לא מקרי השלמת התענית עד צאת הכוכבים] ומכריע הרמ"א דבתענית יחיד דהיינו שיחיד גזר על עצמו תענית לסמוך על הי"א דלא ישלים ומ"מ לכתחלה טוב יותר שיפרש כן בשעת קבלת התענית ובדיעבד אין זה לעיכובא ובת"צ חמירא מזה וצריך להשלים כדין [כו] ואפילו תנאי לא מהני דלאו בדידיה תליא מילתא [כז] וצבור שגזרו על עצמן תענית מחדש בשביל איזה ענין לא חמירא כ"כ ומהני תנאי:

Whereas the Ben Ish Hai and Kaf HaHaim both rule that one must wait(still digging through my notes for exact references on those two).

There is also a shiur [here](http://dev.pidyon.org/component/shiurim/series?tag=fasts) that can be heard on the topic.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a theoretical question. In Australia , Brazil, South Africa, etc. Asara bTeveis is a long summer fast day. 
Rav Scheinberg pasken'ed : ok to make an early Shabos and break fast before sundown

Rav Henkin (posek of Ezras Torah Luach) evidently paskens that is not ok.

When my relatives lived in Melboune Australia they did not know of anyone using Rav Scheinberg psak.

Comment: Are there sources where these psikei halakha can be read?

Comment: for Rav Henkin, look at the Ezras Torah Luach. It states not even to start maariv till after tzais.