# Does an Early Shabbos mean Early Meat during the 9 days?

Tags: shabbat, meat, nine-days

If one makes an early Shabbos during the nine days of Aveilus before Tish'a B'Av, does that mean s/he can eat meat earlier? Or does one still have to wait until it is actually nightfall?

Comment: Or similarly, if you extend shabbos late, can you continue eating meat? Though that's worse as you've now entered "the week of Tisha B'av", which is stricter than the preceding days starting at Rosh Chodesh.

Comment: Does a real _avel_ limit his restrictions to _d'varim sheb'tzin'a_ as soon as he starts _tosefes shabas_?

Comment: @WAF Yes. Pitchei Teshuva YD 400:1

Answer (score 15, accepted):

http://www.kashrut.com/articles/ninedays/

> On Shabbos there is no restriction against eating meat or drinking
>   wine even if one began Shabbos early - any time after plag ha-Minchah.

Comment: Examine Reb Moshe's tshuva: he allows feeding it to kids who won't stay up. But no heter for the family to have their meal early. שו"ת אגרות משה אורח חיים ח"ד סימן כא ובדבר להאכיל לקטנים בע"ש אחר חצות בשר בט' הימים אין שום טעם להתיר זה דמ"ש הם מגדולים בשביל כבוד שבת ואם מחנכין אותם באיסור אכילת בשר כדאיתא במ"ב בס"ק ע' שאף לתינוקות אין מאכילין בשר כהדגמ"ר ליכא טעם שיהיו מותרין להאכילם בע"ש אחר חצות, ורק אם עדיין לא הרגילום לחכות בימי הקיץ עד אחר מעריב אלא מאכילין אותן סעודת שבת בשעה או כשתי שעות קודם קבלת שבת יכולין אז להאכילן בשר.

Comment: @Milwaukee_Rebbe, welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks for the note! The paragraph you quote, about feeding kids *before Shabbat* on late Friday afternoon, seems to be the only part of [the teshuva](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=920&st=&pgnum=37) that addresses Friday. I don't know how R' Neustadt sees therein specific permission for adults to eat meat *after Shabbat starts, before nightfall*. On the other hand, that's certainly not precluded by what R' Moshe does say. Please consider registering your account, to help the site keep track of your contributions.

Comment: @IsaacMoses That's because this Teshuva is not R' Neustadt's source. GershonGold appended the listed source reference from a different statement. This answer is inaccurate.

Comment: Lol, Gershon: you even [accepted elsewhere](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17715/759) that that Teshuva is on a different topic!

Comment: Interesting. @DoubleAA, then what _is_ his source (if you know)?

Comment: @DoubleAA, it does kind of sound like you're feeding the children their סעודת שבת, not just "dinner". How, then, would this happen without parental involvement (for the especially young, non-infant, children he's clearly talking about)?

Comment: @Seth His source is cited in my answer here. RMF in the responsum permits feeding your kids Shabbat food before they go to sleep and before shabbat started for anyone. You have your regular meal later.

Answer (score 4):

An oral ruling of Rabbi Moshe Feinstein (recorded in [Moadei Yeshurun](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Moadei-Yeshurun-compilation-traditions-situations/dp/B0006E5B6S) pg 131 paragraph 8) states:

> One who extends the observance of *Shabbos* by accepting it earlier on Friday or keeping it longer Saturday night, may eat meat and drink wine or grape juice during the extended period.

The footnote there (#62) references the oral ruling as well as one of Rabbi Feinstein's student's responsa, [Rivevos Ephraim 1:367:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1081&pgnum=285), who doesn't cite Rabbi Feinstein (as there is no prior written record of this ruling of his) but comes to the same conclusion only in the instance of extending Shabbos earlier into Friday.

(h/t Rabbi Doniel Neustadt for pointing me to Moadei Yeshurun)

Answer (score -3):

Shabbos is dorita, Prohibition on meet is drabannan

Comment: And therefore??

Comment: The issue here isn't _shabas_ and meat eating coming into conflict. It is the delimitation of the prohibition on meat. Since one does not need to give up on the _mitzva mid'Oraisa_ of _kidush_ (or that of _tosefes shabas_) in order to refrain from eating meat, the two actions could coexist.

Comment: To further what @WAF said, when 9 Av falls out on Motza'ei Shabbat, one must fast starting at sunset, even though the fast is clearly d'Rabbanan.  This is true even if the fast is nidcheh, where we might expect even more kulot.

Comment: Also when 10 tevet is on friday we fast until tzeit.

Comment: The prohibition on meat and wine in this case is only a minhag (not a derabanan) as it is not the Seudah Mafseket.

Comment: @DoubleAA - Could you please provide sources for the statements that you mentioned in the previous two comments?

Comment: @AdamMosheh See Shulchan Aruch OC 249:4 and 551:9 respectively.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/asara-bteveis-on-a-friday