# Early Shabbos during 9 days

Tags: shabbat, grapes-wine, kiddush, nine-days

Is it permitted to bring in Shabbos early during the 9 days and make Kiddush?  I know that the prevailing custom for Havdallah is to do it over something other than wine, but obviously this cannot be done for kiddush on Shabbos evening. Is there any connection between these, or are they totally separate because havdallah occurs after Shabbos is over, while Kiddush occurs when you have already accepted Shabbos?

Comment: Once one brings in Shabbas after plag it is considered Shabbas and one can use wine and havdallah is the procedure which concludes the Shabbas so some dont use wine since it is considered chol(alot of people use wine anyways see Shuclhan Aruch)

Comment: related to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9193/does-an-early-shabbos-mean-early-meat-before-tisha-bav

Comment: One quibble: Kiddush Friday night can be made on bread, so the statement "obviously this cannot be done for kiddush on Shabbos evening" is not correct.

Comment: @DovF Isn't that only bdi eved?

Comment: Well obviously this isn't an ideal situation...

Comment: @sam, can you post that as an answer with a source so I can accept it?

Comment: Is this a dupe of @AvrohomYitzchok's link?

Comment: What if you did Havdala early on Shabbat afternoon?

Comment: @DoubleAA What?

Comment: @Daniel That's the parallel question which could shed light on this one. Do the general no-wine practices still apply when it's still Shabbat.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.kashrut.com/articles/ninedays/

> On Shabbos there is no restriction against eating meat or drinking wine even if one began Shabbos early - any time after plag ha-Minchah.

We see from here that you can make Kiddush early.

This is Gershon Gold’s answer to the question Avrohom Yitzchok linked above.